# How to change order of divs on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I need to reorder the divs when screen size is less than 480px.

I don't want to use `position: absolute` because the height of the green area may vary due to amount of text.

I need the small screen order to be red, green, red, green, red, green (each red being on top of the immediate green and width being 100%).

Any idea? Many thanks

```css
*, html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full_half {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100px;
}

.pic {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
}

.text {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 120px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .full_half {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .text{
     padding: 0 0 !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="full_half pic"></div>
    <div class="full_half text">test</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="full_half text">test</div>
    <div class="full_half pic"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="full_half pic"></div>
    <div class="full_half text">
        dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf<br />
        dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf<br />
        dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

SOLVED:

I have finally managed to changed the order by applying flexbox to the container (only when width is less than 480px).

css change:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .container {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    .pic {
      order: 1;
    }

    .text{
     order: 2;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vquf7z7b/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [**CSS Flexbox**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) you can control the visual order of elements with the `order` property and the x/y direction of the divs with the `flex-direction` property.

Here are a few simple adjustments to your code that make your layout work:

**CSS**

```
.container {
     display: flex; /* NEW */
    /* width: 100%; */
    /* display: inline-block; */
    /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .full_half {  width: 100%; }
    .text      {  padding: 0 0 !important; }
    .container { flex-direction: column; }         /* NEW */
    .container:nth-child(2) > .pic { order: -1; }  /* NEW */
}
```

Now when the screen size is less than 480px the divs are stacked in a single column and the order is red, green, red, green, red, green.

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.full_half {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.pic {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
}
.text {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px 120px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .full_half {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .text {
    padding: 0 0 !important;
  }
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container:nth-child(2) > .pic {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="full_half pic"></div>
  <div class="full_half text">test</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full_half text">test</div>
  <div class="full_half pic"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="full_half pic"></div>
  <div class="full_half text">
    dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf
    <br />dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf
    <br />dfdfdfdfdfdffdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9jjLeoj/2/)

In the example above, child elements of the flex container (`.container`) are aligned in a row, which is the default layout of a flexbox (`flex-direction: row`).

Each child element is `order: 0` by default. By giving the `div` with the `.pic` class in the second `.container` an `order` value of -1, it gets positioned before its sibling  (`div` with `.text` with a value of 0). We could also have given the first sibling a value of 1, thus moving it after `div` with `.pic`. [Learn more about the `order` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

By changing the value of  `flex-direction` from its default (`row`) to `column`, the divs stack up in a single column. [Learn more about the `flex-direction` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction)

---

***Browser support:*** *Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*